# Does something like CanCan (authorization library) exist for flask and python

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, flask

I love [@rbates](https://twitter.com/rbates) [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) ruby library for authorization.  Was wondering if anything similar existed for python / flask ?

I guess there are three main requirements:

1. simple declarative way of defining abilities ([here is how CanCan does it](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities))
2. decorator for flask routes
3. fine-grained way for checking abilities in other parts of the code.  i.e. `if current_user.can('post::edit')` or something

[Or, what is the one obvious way to do it? (PEP-20)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

---

Current Options:

- [Flask Simple Authorization](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/98/) (leaning towards something like this for now.)
- [Flask Principal](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/)  (They all feel a bit heavy weight to me)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One year later, I ended up writing one:

https://github.com/jtushman/bouncer

https://github.com/jtushman/flask-bouncer

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you keep an eye on [Cork](http://cork.firelet.net/). Currently it's an authentication and authorization framework just for [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/), but on the roadmap is Flask support. Pretty awesome.

Comment: Cork author here: any suggestion on how to support Flask is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this package in a LinkedIn post a while back.
I never really checked it out, but it looked to have constant updates

Authomatic is an authorization / authentication client library for Python web applications inspired by Alex Vagin’s Simpleauth. In fact, I almost named it Deadsimpleauth, but that name would be too long for a succinct library.

http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/
https://github.com/peterhudec/authomatic

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what your looking for, but you might want to take a look at Flask-Auth. http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Auth/

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for.  It has a decorator, and a current_user object you can access and add methods to.

https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Could you include an example of how to use it in case the link goes dead?